# swap two elements in Haskell by value

Tags: haskell, swap

I'm new to Haskell. I need a function to swap two elements in a list when I know only the values.

For example:

```
swap 5 6 [1,5,7,6,4,3,2] -> [1,6,7,5,4,3,2]
```

`5` and `6` are the values not the index, and the index of the values can be any.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if there are multiple elements with the given values, or only one of the values is present? `map (\x -> if x == a then b else if x == b then a else x) list` would solve it for a particular answer to these questions.

Comment: let's say no duplicates if it's simpler

Comment: The simplest is the above. If you have `k` 5's and `m` 6's before, you'll have `k` 6's and `m` 5's after. If you need to take multiplicities of either value in the list into account, in whichever way, it becomes more complicated.

Comment: wow thx daniel for the so fast answer, i wouldn't never thought about using map:) i think i dislike haskell but i have to do my homework

Answer (score 7):

It might help if you think about this task as reconstructing the list with the values swapped.  The type signature is going to be like this.  You're taking in two numbers to be swapped, and a list.

```
swap :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

You've got a couple of cases now.  If the list is empty, that's easy.  This is your base case.

```
swap _ _ [] = []
```

If the list isn't empty, then you've got two choices.  Either the head of the list is a number you are interested in, or it's not.  In the case where it matches, swap the value, otherwise just rebuild the list.

```
swap n m (x:xs)
  | n == x = m : (swap n m xs)
  | m == x = n : (swap n m xs)
  | otherwise = x : (swap n m xs)
```

Once you've got this situation, you can see that you're doing an operation on every element.  Now you can convert it over to the `map` solution (which is far more idiomatic!).

Comment: i tried something like this but it didn't work, now i understand:D

Answer (score 5):

```
swap a b = map (\x -> if x == a then b else if x == b then a else x)
```

EDIT: Ah, I am afraid I only noticed that this question was answered in a comment above in the exact same way after I posted my answer. Apologies.